# How to change toggle view State appearance: android

Tags: android

I want to change my toggle view enabled and disable state appearance. Can someone tell me how to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a selector in drawable folder of your project

which will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off"  />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on"  />
</selector>
```

Don't forget to keep toggle_off.png, and toggle_on.png in your drawable folder.

and then apply this selector in your toggle button as follows:

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/togglerToggle"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_indication_selecter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

toggle_indication_selecter is selector name.

Answer (score 0):

[toggle button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) is having selector file that can maintain state. you can see below toggle button code and its selector file also.

```
<ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/toggleAutoChange"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/toggle_sel"
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn="" />
```

selector toggle_sel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
</selector>
```

You can change drawables according to your requirement.But above is state that you can maintain.